# download getRs function from Hmisc

Tags: hmisc

I have the latest version of R,Rstudio, Hmisc- which should has getRs function..same error with knitrSet function.

require(Hmisc)

> getRs() 
>   Error: could not find function "getRs"
>
> knitrSet('reg', width=80)
>   Error: could not find function "knitrSet"
>   help.search("knitrSet",package="Hmisc")   #not found
>   ?Hmisc::knitrSet                           #not found
>   No documentation for ‘knitrSet’ in specified packages and libraries:
>   options ( url.method ='libcurl ')

Thanks for your help.
Al